# Is there a package that makes traceback and error handling easier?

Tags: python, flutter, dart, traceback

I come from a python background, and error traceback back there is so easy to follow and allows for quick exception identification.

I was wondering if there was a package or a plugin (VSCode) that formats or makes error tracing easier in Flutter.

For non Python user, here are two examples:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/example.py", line 4, in <module>
    greet('Chad')
  File "/path/to/example.py", line 2, in greet
    print('Hello, ' + someon)
NameError: name 'someon' is not defined
```

```
$ python example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/greetings.py", line 19, in <module>
    greet('Chad', greting='Yo')
TypeError: greet() got an unexpected keyword argument 'greting'
```

Comment: Can you give an example of some code you have difficulties with and an example of how Python are solving the problem for us non-python developers?

Comment: @julemand101 I just edited my post.

Comment: I believe this is already done.

Comment: Could you be more specific about exactly what you're looking for?  You already can get an error message from a Dart `Exception` or `Error` and can get a string representation of the corresponding `StackTrace`.

Comment: I just seem to find it harder to identify the error, especially when the error stems from the emulator and not in the IDE before runTime.

Comment: Take a look at [Catcher](https://pub.dev/packages/catcher) and check if helps you.